# Changing iframed page zoom dynamically based on size of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to detect height and width of iframe from framed page, and set zoom based on it so page fits content of iframe by 100 width.

For example I have a page whose min. width is 960px, but someone would like to show my page in 690px width iframe without scrollbars.

How would I detect that and scale content based on that so people can see whole page but scaled smaller?

Comment: I suggest you to use "viewport" to auto detect the window size (including iframe) , then it will import right style file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta concept could be the following:

```
// Check if window is inside of an iframe
if (window.self !== window.top) {
    var optimalSize = 500; // desired width of the page
    document.body.style.zoom = optimalSize / window.innerWidth;
}
```

Another option could be using media queries to apply proper styles - I think this would be the best for your situation.